# WebGL: How do I get the position of every pixel in fragment shader?

Tags: html, opengl-es, webgl

I know I could use `gl_Position` to get every vertex's position, but if it's possible to get every pixel's position in fragment shader ?

I want to change the alpha value of some pixel area.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
vec2 gl_FragCoord
```

It will return you position of the fragment on the screen in pixels.
If you pass uniform `vec2 screenResolution` then you could play with that two values to determine where exactly on the screen is pixel, in which part and such.

This is a built-in variable, so you can use it whenever you want in fragment shader.

Here's one example of usage just to demonstrate: http://goo.gl/AG7UO

If you want woorld coordinate of the fragment, then you should use `varying` variable.

Vertex shader:

```
varying vec3 vPos;
attribute vec3 aVertexCoord;
uniform mat4 uMVMat;
uniform mat4 uProjMat;

void main() {
    vPos = uMVMat * aVertexPos;
    gl_Position = uProjMat * vPos;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
varying vec3 vPos;
void main() {
    // do something
}
```

Hope this helps.